# Remove the first or last char so the values from a column should start with numbers

Tags: pandas

I'm new to Pandas and I'd like to ask your advice.
Let's take this dataframe:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'Dimensions': ['22.67x23.5', '22x24.6', '45x56', 'x23x56.22','46x23x','34x45'],
                     'Other': [59, 29, 73, 56,48,22]})
```

I want to detect the lines that starts with "x" (line 4) or ends with "x" (line 5) and then remove them so my dataframe should look like this

```
Dimensions  Other
22.67x23.5  59
22x24.6     29
45x56       73
23x56.22    56
46x23       48
34x45       22
```

I wanted to create a function and apply it to a column

```
def remove_x(x):
    if (x.str.match('^[a-zA-Z]') == True):
        x = x[1:]
        return x
    if (x.str.match('.*[a-zA-Z]$') == True):
        x = x[:-1]
        return x
```

If I apply this function to the column

```
df_test['Dimensions'] = df_test['Dimensions'].apply(remove_x)
```

I got an error 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
I delete 'str' from the function and re-run all but no success.

What should I do?
Thank you for any suggestions or if there is another way to do it I'm interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `str.strip`:

```
df_test['Dimensions'] = df_test['Dimensions'].str.strip('x')
```

For general patterns, you can try `str.replace`:

```
df_test['Dimensions'].str.replace('(^x)|(x$)','')
```

Output:

```
   Dimensions  Other
0  22.67x23.5     59
1     22x24.6     29
2       45x56     73
3    23x56.22     56
4       46x23     48
5       34x45     22
```

Answer (score 0):

**@QuangHoang's answer is better (for simplicity and efficiency)**, but here's what went wrong in your approach.  In your `apply` function, you are making calls to accessing the `str` methods of a Series or DataFrame.  But when you call `df_test['Dimensions'].apply(remove_x)`, the values passed to `remove_x` are the elements of `df_test['Dimensions']`, aka the `str` values themselves.  So you should construct the function as if `x` is an incoming `str`.

Here's how you could implement that (avoiding any regex):

```
def remove_x(x):
    if x[0] == 'x':
        return x[1:]
    elif x[-1] == 'x':
        return x[:-1]
    else:
        return x
```

More idiomatically:

```
def remove_x(x):
    x.strip('x')
```

Or even:

```
df_test['Dimensions'] = df_test['Dimensions'].apply(lambda x : x.strip('x'))
```

All that said, [better to not use `apply`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54432584/13386979) and follow the built-ins shown by Quang.